# UART DMA Receive Overwriting Issue

Tags: c, embedded

I have designed my own communication protocol in the code below. but I have a problem. when reading the data from the slave device, the first data reading takes place smoothly, but when reading the data after that, the data writing process continues from the last position it left instead of starting from the beginning.

Example:

first data that slave sent: AA 05 FF 01 8F DA FA
it reads the way I want it to:

0xaa
0x5
0xff
0x1
0xda8f
0xfa

second data that slave sent: AA 05 FF 02 8F DA FA
there is an overwriting issue:

0x5
0xff
0x2
0x8f
0xfada
0x0

### why could it be happening? I'm waiting for your help.

rs422.c file:

```
/*
 * rs422.c
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 5, 2024
 *      Author: yazilim
 */

#include "rs422.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"




void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size){


    if(huart->Instance == USART1){

        memcpy(&rs422.receivedFrame, rs422.uartBuffer, sizeof(Comframe));

        if (rs422.receivedFrame.odByte == 0xFF) {
                // Hata durumu algılandı, hatanın türüne göre işlem yap
                switch (rs422.receivedFrame.dataByte) {
                    case 0x01:
                        // Varsayılan hata kodu
                        // İletişimin kopması, veri paketinin eksik gelmesi gibi durumlar
                        rs422.errorCode = 1;
                        break;
                    case 0x02:
                        // Checksum hatası
                        rs422.errorCode = 2;
                        break;
                    case 0x03:
                        // Data length hatası
                        rs422.errorCode = 3;
                        break;
                    // Diğer hata durumlarına göre case'ler ekleyebilirsiniz.
                    default:
                        // Tanımsız hata durumu
                        rs422.errorCode = 9;
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                // Hata durumu yok, normal veri işleme
                // OD ve diğer verileri kullanarak işlemleri yapabilirsiniz.
            }

        memset(&rs422.receivedFrame, 0, sizeof(rs422.receivedFrame));
        memset(rs422.uartBuffer, 0, sizeof(rs422.uartBuffer));

        //HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(rs422.huart1_ptr, (uint8_t*)&rs422.receivedFrame, sizeof(rs422.receivedFrame));
        HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(rs422.huart1_ptr, rs422.uartBuffer, sizeof(rs422.uartBuffer));
        __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(rs422.hdma_usart1_rx_ptr, DMA_IT_HT);

    }


}

    //veri işleme örnek
/*
     if (strstr(StoredChar,"set=")!= NULL){      //eğer gelen değer set içeriyorsa
             int result = sscanf(StoredChar,"set=%d",&intvalue);  //değerin set= den sonraki kısmını integer'a ata. hata kontrolunu de result ile yap
             if (result == 1)
                   {
                     // Başarılı bir şekilde tamsayı okundu
                     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                     HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, "Ok\r\n", 6,100);
                     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                     memset(StoredChar, 0, sizeof(StoredChar));
                   }
             else{
                 //tamsayı okunamadi.
                 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, "Hata: set'den sonra Geçersiz değer girildi.\r\n", 47,100);
                 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                 memset(StoredChar, 0, sizeof(StoredChar));
             }

        }
     else if(strcmp(StoredChar,"read")== 0){

         //transmit etmeden önce int değerini stringe çevir.
         char strvalue[20]={0};
         sprintf(strvalue,"%d",intvalue);
         //stringe çevrildi.

         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET); //veri gonderme moduna gec
         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, strvalue, 20,100);
         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, "\r\n", 2,100); // Yeni satır karakterleri için ayrı bir iletim yap
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Veri alma moduna gec.
         memset(StoredChar,0,sizeof(StoredChar));

     }
     else{
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET); //veri gonderme moduna gec
         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, "beklenmeyen deger girildi.\r\n", 30,100);
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DE_485_GPIO_Port, DE_485_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Veri alma moduna gec.
         memset(StoredChar,0,sizeof(StoredChar));
     }
     memset(receivedData, 0, sizeof(StoredChar));
     */
//}

void Rs422Init(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart1,UART_HandleTypeDef *huart3,DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma_usart3_rx,DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma_usart1_rx) {

    strcpy(rs422.receivedData, "");
    strcpy(rs422.StoredChar, "");
    memset(rs422.uartBuffer, 0, sizeof(rs422.uartBuffer));

    rs422.huart1_ptr = huart1;
    rs422.hdma_usart1_rx_ptr = hdma_usart1_rx;

    // Comframe yapısındaki alanları sıfırla
    rs422.frame.startByte = 0;
    rs422.frame.dataLengthByte = 0;
    rs422.frame.odByte = 0;
    rs422.frame.dataByte = 0;
    rs422.frame.crcByte = 0;
    rs422.frame.stopByte = 0;


}

void Rs422Receive() {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS422_DE_GPIO_Port, RS422_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    //HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(rs422.huart1_ptr, (uint8_t*)&rs422.receivedFrame, sizeof(rs422.receivedFrame));
    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(rs422.huart1_ptr, rs422.uartBuffer, sizeof(rs422.uartBuffer));
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(rs422.hdma_usart1_rx_ptr, DMA_IT_HT);
}

/*
void Rs422Receive(){

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS422_DE_GPIO_Port, RS422_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(rs422.huart1_ptr, rs422.receivedData, sizeof(rs422.receivedData));
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(rs422.hdma_usart1_rx_ptr, DMA_IT_HT);



}*/

void Rs422Transmit(uint8_t odByte, uint8_t dataByte) {
    // Veriyi CRC değeri ile birlikte güncelle
    rs422.frame.odByte = odByte;
    rs422.frame.dataByte = dataByte;
    calculateCRC(&rs422);

    // Başlangıç ve bitiş baytlarını güncelle
    rs422.frame.startByte = 0xAA;
    rs422.frame.stopByte = 0xFA;

    // Veri uzunluğunu güncelle
    rs422.frame.dataLengthByte = sizeof(rs422.frame) - 3; // Start byte, data length byte ve stop byte hariç

    // uartBuffer oluştur ve verileri doldur
    sprintf(rs422.uartBuffer, "%02X %02X %02X %02X %05X %02X \n", rs422.frame.startByte, rs422.frame.dataLengthByte, rs422.frame.odByte, rs422.frame.dataByte, rs422.frame.crcByte, rs422.frame.stopByte);

    // Transmit işlemi
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS422_DE_GPIO_Port, RS422_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    rs422.check = HAL_UART_Transmit(rs422.huart1_ptr, (uint8_t*)rs422.uartBuffer, strlen(rs422.uartBuffer), 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS422_DE_GPIO_Port, RS422_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}


/*
void Rs422Transmit(){

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS422_DE_GPIO_Port, RS422_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    rs422.check = HAL_UART_Transmit(rs422.huart1_ptr, "Ok\r\n", 6,100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS422_DE_GPIO_Port, RS422_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

}*/

// CRC-16-CCITT lookup table
static const uint16_t crcTable[256] = {
    // CRC-16-CCITT lookup table values (0x1021 polynomial)
    // Her bir değer 8-bit için CRC'nin nasıl değişeceğini belirtir
    // Daha fazla bilgi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks
};

// CRC hesaplama fonksiyonları


void calculateCRC(Rs422 *rs422) {

    uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF; // Başlangıç değeri

    // Veri uzunluğu, OD ve Data değerleri CRC ile güncellenir
    crc = updateCRC(rs422->frame.dataLengthByte, crc);
    crc = updateCRC(rs422->frame.odByte, crc);
    crc = updateCRC(rs422->frame.dataByte, crc);

        // CRC değeri Rs422 yapısının içindeki Comframe altındaki crcByte alanına atanır
        rs422->frame.crcByte = crc;
    }

uint16_t updateCRC(uint8_t data, uint16_t crc) {
    crc ^= (uint16_t)data << 8; // XOR işlemi

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (crc & 0x8000) {
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021; // Eğer en üst bit 1 ise XOR ve shift işlemi
        } else {
            crc <<= 1; // Eğer en üst bit 0 ise sadece shift işlemi
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

rs422.h file:

```
/*
 * rs422.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 8, 2024
 *      Author: yazilim
 */

#ifndef INC_RS422_H_
#define INC_RS422_H_

#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "main.h"



typedef struct{

    uint8_t startByte;
    uint8_t dataLengthByte;
    uint8_t odByte;
    uint8_t dataByte;
    uint16_t crcByte; //16 bit crc
    uint8_t stopByte;

} Comframe;





typedef struct{

    uint8_t receivedData[100];
    uint8_t StoredChar[100];
    UART_HandleTypeDef *huart1_ptr;
    DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma_usart1_rx_ptr;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef check;
    Comframe frame;
    Comframe receivedFrame;
    Comframe receivedFrameTemp;
    uint8_t uartBuffer[35];
    uint8_t errorCode;
} Rs422;

Rs422 rs422;

//fonk tanımları

uint16_t updateCRC(uint8_t data, uint16_t crc);



#endif /* INC_RS422_H_ */
```

Example:

first data that slave sent: AA 05 FF 01 8F DA FA
it reads the way I want it to:

0xaa
0x5
0xff
0x1
0xda8f
0xfa

second data that slave sent: AA 05 FF 02 8F DA FA
there is an overwriting issue:

0x5
0xff
0x2
0x8f
0xfada
0x0

Comment: You aren't using size which is passed into the receive function.  Presumably that is the number of bytes received.  So that is the amount you need to move into your buffers.  Also, there is no guarantee that a full packet will be received in Serial Comms.  I'd recommend a state machine around the incoming data, it appears your packet has a sync byte.